# Is there a way to add personal local notes or annotations to lines of files without affecting the files themselves?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Often times, while trying to read and understand code or debug an issue, I would like to annotate certain parts of files with my own notes.  For multiple reasons, I don't want to add my notes to the files themselves.  Is there a way to add local notes/annotations to files in IntelliJ so that they persist on my machine, but don't effect the project in any way?

I picture something like a diff-viewer where the left side is a file I'm reviewing, and the right side contains my notes and the two are in sync such that if I modify the original file, my notes will remain in sync with the lines they pertain to.

Comment: Something like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8351-code-comments?

Comment: Yea, pretty close!  Would be nicer if it showed the notes side-by-side in the main editor window, but this certainly fulfills most of my needs for now, thanks for the reference!